# Why can't I align content inside bootstrap column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've set relative position for my row and then I tried to align my social buttons to the bottom right corner but failed ;(

I've also set absolute position for my social buttons class and it doesn't seem to align properly. Why is this so?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexnotonfire/cpveg8Lo/)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row fixed-height">    
      <div class="col-xs-4">

          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            Some button!
          </button>

       </div>

      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="social-buttons">

          <div class="btn-group-xs">

            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
            </button>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron {
    margin: 10px;
}
.row {
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: solid;
}

.fixed-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.social-buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't align it right because you have a div that spans 8 cols next to it.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall So what could I do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cpveg8Lo/1/ Moved your button into the `8` col class with a css property of align-right. Not sure if that worked for your implementation though.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cpveg8Lo/3/

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh No, I need to place it on the bottom right corner.

Comment: @BillyLogan, I hope this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/cpveg8Lo/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:http://jsfiddle.net/cpveg8Lo/5/

**CSS**

Add position as relative in row css

```
.row {
    margin: 2px 0;
    border: solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

and make the following change in social button css

```
.social-buttons{ 
    position:absolute;    
    right: 0;
    padding-right:0px;
    bottom:0;
}
```

**HTML**

Update your html as shown below,

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row fixed-height">    
      <div class="col-xs-4">            
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            Some button!
          </button>            
       </div>          
      <div class="col-xs-8 social-buttons">
        <div class="pull-right">            
          <div class="btn-group-xs">            
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
            </button>            
          </div>            
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here check this snippet. This will keep those button vertically centered as well. Try this -

```css
.jumbotron {
    margin: 10px;
}
.row {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: solid;
}

.fixed-height {
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.social-buttons{
    position:absolute;
    right:15px;
    top: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -o-transform: translatey(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-50%);
    transform: translatey(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row fixed-height">    
      <div class="col-xs-4">
            
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
            Some button!
          </button>
            
       </div>
          
      <div class="social-buttons">
           
          <div class="btn-group-xs">
            
            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
            </button>
            
          </div>
            
      </div>
          
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```